# How to stop timer after ten seconds in javascript using setInterval and clearInterval?

Tags: javascript, timer, settimeout, setinterval, clearinterval

I was wondering how can I stop a timer after ten seconds in javascript using setInterval and clearInterval??
Here's my code example, could you please tell me where I'm going wrong:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

var tt=setInterval(function(){startTime()},1000);


function startTime()
{
  var today = new Date();
  var h=today.getHours();
  var m=today.getMinutes();
  var s=today.getSeconds();
  // add a zero in front of numbers<10
  m=checkTime(m);
  s=checkTime(s);
  today=checkTime(today);
  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=s;

}

function checkTime(tt)
{
if (tt==10)
  {
    tt="0" + tt;
    console.log(tt);
    clearInterval(tt);
  }
return tt;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="startTime()">
<div id="txt"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bending time-space not quite working for you, huh :P...

Comment: Your code makes no sense! `checkTime` is being called with 3 different values?

Comment: Consider how _setInterval_ can be dangerous if your function takes longer to complete than the given interval.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `startTime()` will run every second, make a counter to increment to 10 inside of it, then clear the interval.

```
var tt=setInterval(function(){startTime()},1000);
var counter = 1;

function startTime()
{
  if(counter == 10) {
    clearInterval(tt);
  } else {
    counter++;
  }

  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML= counter;  
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eMBW2/)

Answer (score 16):

you can set timeout on clear like this right after you set the interval:

```
var tt = setInterval(function(){ startTime() }, 1000);
setTimeout(function() { clearInterval(tt); }, 10000);
```

Comment: I don't know why, but this answer was downvoted even though it's the simplest answer of all and it works. It sets an interval and clears it after 10 seconds. That's exactly what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 3):

Because you named a local variable named tt which does not let you access the global variable tt. Very bad planning on variable names.

Your code also will not stop at 10 seconds, it will stop when the time is at 10 seconds or 10 minutes.

```
function checkTime(xtt)
{
if (xtt==10)
  {
    xtt="0" + xtt;
    console.log(xtt);
    clearInterval(tt);
  }
return xtt;
}
```

Comment: Nice catch(i think - can barely read the stuff), mind answering the question next :P?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me.

```
var tt = setInterval(function(){ startTime() }, 1000);

setTimeout(function() { clearInterval(tt); }, 10000);
```

Comment: If you want to thank Tomzan for his answer, you should upvote it instead of adding an answer

Comment: As already noted before, this is a exact duplicate of above anwser.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that

```
setInterval(startTime, 1000).pipe(takeUntil(timer(10000)));
```